# Reach out to CloudBerry

Tags: discussion, outsourcing

CloudBerry seems to be outsourcing off topic questions to the main site:

http://www.cloudberrylab.com/support.aspx

[image]

I've seen many bad and off topic questions/answers in the [cloudberry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloudberry).

[Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6795820/alex) seems to be the right contact.

Comment: From my cursory examination of this, this doesn't seem to be a programming-related product. Most of these questions are about installing and running something, and are outside of the scope of the site. The problem is them directing these questions here at all.

Comment: I'll reach out to them.

Comment: I like how this straight-up says that Stack Overflow is the "right place" for any question that begins *"How do I...?"* And by like, I mean facepalm.

Comment: And the "start discussion" CTA is more or less exactly the opposite of the aim!

Comment: Can't even spell it right...

Comment: User [Antoine](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6748044/antoine) seems to be associated with CloudBerry, let's hope they see this question and provide an answer.

Comment: My problem is with the color. That is the worst representation of orange that I've ever seen.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/3144373/evgeny is probably also a company employee.

Comment: @CodyGray "How do I...get a question ban?" Click here to start a discussion on StackOverflow.

Comment: @TinyGiant maybe it's a hint. Blue is exactly the opposite of orange (complementary colors). So maybe when they say you should ask those questions on SO, they mean exactly the opposite.

Comment: It might make sense to direct them to Server Fault; their advice on how to ask on a SE site is actually alright, it's just that how to operate a backup tool is slightly outside of SO's scope.

Comment: Quite a good alternative to a ticketing system they implemented. Very cost effective.

Comment: Hang tight folks. I think I'm going to have to use ..... ***a telephone*** ... <gasp>

Comment: @TimPost whoa. first time ive ever heard that mentioned on stackoverflow.

Comment: @TimPost surely you must mean google voice?

Comment: With the continuous increase in websites pulling crap like this, has there ever been consideration to allow companies to use SO as sort of their own support system? It sounds like they love this site as much as we do and would rather adopt an existing platform over developing their own software. I haven't scoured the Meta site for this topic but would it ever be considered to allow companies to appoint their own employees as experts of a given tag and only allow the experts to answer such questions?

Comment: It looks like for paying customers they are offering their own support on their site, but for free ones they ask to use reddit or SO :D

Comment: @EhsanSajjad hence the outsourcing tag

Comment: @DanielA.White Now there are two close votes o_O

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Ask Ubuntu is official (as in affiliated with Canonical Ltd), so there is precedent.  I think SO-the-company would prefer to create more Stack Exchange sites than to sell a publicly-accessible version of Stack Overflow Enterprise, but maybe if the price is right...

Comment: Seriously? This question does not appear to seek input and discussion from the community? How so?

Comment: @TinyGiant: Maybe some VTC robots got confused, because they didn't find a question mark in the question...

Comment: @Tiny to be frank, it doesn't. It's asking the Stack Overflow staff to do something. But the precedence is that this is the correct way to address issues like this.

Comment: @monkey *"It sounds like they love this site as much as we do and would rather adopt an existing platform over developing their own software."* That is one possible conclusion. Another, slightly more cynical, conclusion is, they'd rather outsource to something that is free and doesn't require them to make a significant investment in support staff.

Comment: @CodyGray Don't you worry, I have enough cynicism to supply all of us for a lifetime. Put CloudBerry on a ban list and do not allow any iteration of the word via subject, body, nor tags unless they would like to appoint their own cronnies to the depths of those contemptible questions. As a matter of fact, don't allow non-cronnies to answer those questions.

Comment: They are one of about 200 companies that do that. At least 200.

Comment: Any luck @TimPost?

Comment: @DanielA.White He's still trying to copy/paste the number to the real-life telephone...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Sadly, in recent weeks I actually wrote a lengthy document by hand and decided to replicate it into a Word doc. About half way through my brain shifted and said "oh wait, I should just copy+paste" and proceeded to hit Ctrl+C and at that moment I realized how much futility was involved in being forced to hand-write essays from K-8th grade.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Excellent point, makes me think of SalesForce and WordPress as well. The only issue is that CloudBerry would have to make it through Area51 and based on the subpar-ness of their present state, it wouldn't even make it past the registration page...

Comment: All I see is a chance for SE to make bank providing commercial "social support" exchanges for companies that want to pull this sort of thing.

Comment: @gelliott181 nonononononononono. If we start wrapping up money into that, it'll become unmanageable. How do you tell a company that PAYS you to host their questions "yeah... we don't want you to post such crap here"...

Comment: @patrice This was meant to be a joke. SE has morals, that would only be viable if they didn't. That said, the Canonical deal for Ask Ubuntu is a precedent to the service's availability to SE partners.

Comment: @gelliott181 Hard to tell sarcasm on the interwebs :P happy to know it wasn't serious lol.

Answer (score 2):

I have edited the [cloudberry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloudberry) tag wiki to warn users against posting general product support requests and provide a link to our on-topic guidance in the help center. This may not completely stop the flood but it should help a little.

Comment: Because every new 1 rep user reads tag wikis. Oh wait they don't. Oh well, at least you tried.

Comment: I feel like if ONE user reads the tag and doesn't post because of it, it's one post prevented. Way more than a cynical comment will do ;).

Comment: @Patrice great point. Each off-topic post not only distracts us from answering on-topic questions, it advances a user along that dark path where there are only question bans and gnashing of teeth.

Comment: @GillBates - It's helpful to be able to point users to something that specifically says their use of the tag is incorrect when they complain that the third party company said it was OK.