# Burn the web! [w3c]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, tag-disambiguation

I was [made aware](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339607/reach-out-to-w3c) of the existence of the [w3c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/w3c) tag, today.

This seems like a meta tag that should probably be burninated, so let's have a look at [the criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191):

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied?** and **is it unambiguous?**

   The tag by itself says nothing about a question other than that it's about something related to w3c. It's saying just as much as [microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft) (which was [burninated, and even blacklisted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284167/blacklist-the-microsoft-and-apple-tags)). It's quite ambiguous.
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

   The concept of [w3c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/w3c) is an organisation. By itself, this isn't necessarily programming-related.
   Questions about [w3c's standards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/w3c+standards) should probably have a tag of their own, and they can be on-topic, provided they're not asking for opinions.
   Other than that, the questions about w3c's [process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40388249/whats-the-w3c-publication-workflow) or [terms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38553108/what-does-tr-and-cr-stand-for-in-w3c-drafts), for example, don't really seem on-topic for Stack Overflow.
3. **Does the tag add *any* meaningful information to the post?**

   Related tags:
   [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) × 347
   [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) × 211
   [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) × 149
   [html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5) × 147
   [w3c-validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/w3c-validation) × 105
   [xhtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xhtml) × 97
   [validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/validation) × 94
   [xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml) × 83
   [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) × 62
   [dom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dom) × 57
   [css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css3) × 38
   [web-standards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-standards) × 35 and some more ...

   This is all over the place, but without those tags, [w3c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/w3c) is pretty meaningless.
   1 user committed to a [w3c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/w3c)   [documentation proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/w3c/commit).

   The top users in this tag have significant activity in the related tags. Which implies that the following is a result of the [w3c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/w3c) tag being applied to questions with those tags.
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

   This tag's meaning is rather vague. By itself, it doesn't mean anything yet.
   When combined with [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), it's *probably* about JavaScript standards. When combined with [xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml), it's *probably* about w3c's [xml schema](https://www.w3.org/XML/).

Altogether, from my perspective, the tag seems too ambiguous to stay on SO.

Comment: But.. but... you'll ruin their cost-free customer care policy... :(

Comment: Wouldn't you assume that a [w3c] tag on a *programming* site refers to the W3C's standards? A lot of the ambiguity here seems manufactured.

Comment: @CodyGray: Assume, maybe. But then that should be clarified in the tag wiki. The tag should then be removed from 933 questions that [aren't about standards](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/w3c+-standards), leaving only 31 [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/w3c+standards).

Comment: Haha. Hold on a minute. You're railing about the existence of a [w3c] tag when we have a [standards] tag?

Comment: @CodyGray: one burnination at a time. ;-)

Comment: There might be questions specifically relating to the use of W3C's [developer tools](https://www.w3.org/developers/tools/), but those would probably be better served with either [tag:w3c-tools] (or something similar), or tags for each individual tool.

Comment: @ZevSpitz: Indeed, those should probably have their own tag.

Comment: I agree with @CodyGray: Burnination is harsher than necessary here.  In fact, a topic covering the understanding and interpreting W3C standards as they apply to programming is entirely needed and appropriate.   Burniation needn't be the only remedy for suboptimal use.

Comment: "When combined with [javascript], it's probably about JavaScript standards." That's when you realize JavaScript isn't a W3C standard at all. It's an ECMA standard. Nay, an *implementation* of an ECMA standard. Which makes [w3c] completely out of place in a question that's solely about JavaScript.

Comment: semantics ftw!!

Comment: @BoltClock It's not like we didn't have an [\[ecma\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecma) as well…

Comment: Burn the web along with W3C!

Comment: How about we don't, then say we didn't?

Comment: @TinyGiant How about we do and then never talk about it again?

Comment: @TylerH that is another option.

Comment: That is exactly what is going to happen, Tyler!

Comment: @BoltClock I think it would fine to have [w3c] and [javascript] on a question asking about how a standard is implemented in JavaScript, along with with relevant standard tag.

Comment: @Mike McCaughan: There's that I guess.

Comment: @Manoj given that currently twice as many people disagree with the burnination as agree with it, I wouldn't be so sure.

Comment: @TinyGiant: Twice as many disagree? Where'd you get that idea? This question is at +39/-22.

Comment: @Cerbrus at the time that I posted that comment, there were twice as many upvotes for the answer that disagrees with the request as there were upvotes on the request itself. Currently, there are exactly the same amount of upvotes on the disagreement end as there are on the request itself, while the request itself has more downvotes than the disagreement. All in all, there is no consensus on the matter whatsoever, so no action should be taken. Hence, the comment from Manoj saying "that is exactly what is going to happen" is still incorrect and blatantly in violation of the lack of consensus.

Answer (score 41):

**Disagree.**  The [w3c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/w3c) tag should *not* be burninated.

Instead, anyone bothered by the current ambiguity should endeavor to resolve it to apply to understanding and interpreting W3C standards as they pertain to programming, a valuable topic on a programming site and quite worthy of its own tag.

I do agree that the current tag description ought to be adjusted to emphasize this less ambiguous purpose.  Perhaps the primary tag should really be [w3c-standards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/w3c-standards) with [w3c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/w3c) as a synonym.  But burninating [w3c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/w3c) outright would be throwing the baby out with the bathwater.

Comment: I don't like babies, any way... On a more serious note: This is something I can absolutely agree with. +1

Comment: While we are at it, someone will also need to get [W3C to agree with the tag's purpose](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339607/5743988).

Comment: "While we are at it, someone *should* also get W3C to agree with the tag's purpose." SO is not beholden in anyway to W3C, it would just be polite to inform them.

Comment: w3c-standards is a terrible tag, it doesn't say which standard it's asking about. We don't have a \*-standards tags, but we have ieee-\*, ecma-\*, c++\*, etc.

Comment: @Braiam: I believe that a supplemental [w3c] or [w3c-standards] tag with improved definition would be better than dozens of new parallel [w3c-*] tags at this point in time.

Comment: @kjhughes the thing is: that we already have the tags for those standards, they even predate the very [w3c] tag. Basically, the system will have -1 net tags.

Comment: I think the issue here, is that if anyone tries to resolve the ambiguity of the [w3c] being about standards, they will find that there are already tags which are about each specific standard. We already have tags for [html] [css] [svg] [xml] etc.

Comment: @4castle (and @Braiam): If our goal is a minimal, fully orthogonal, *engineered* tag set, then I agree.  If our goal is a rich, expressive, *evolved* tag set, then I think there's room for a [w3c] or [w3c-standards] tag with a refined definition.

Comment: Our goal is connect the questions with the people that are able to answer them. [w3c] doesn't achieve that goal.

Comment: @Braiam: The value to our back-and-forth is tailing off here.  Thanks for your observations.

Comment: If I'm reading your answer right, do you mean applying [w3c-standards] to questions like "How come (does the spec have an explanation for) so-and-so in HTML/CSS?" or "Why does the HTML/CSS spec mandate/forbid so-and-so?" (incidentally my absolute favorite questions to answer on Stack Overflow)?

Comment: @BoltClock: Yes, so, for example: ***Do*** use [w3-standards] for a question about W3C standard [**rationale**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816764/invalid-css-selector-causes-rule-to-be-dropped-what-is-the-rationale) ([**and another**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26642421/why-does-the-w3c-xml-schema-specification-allow-integers-to-have-leading-zeros), *where a W3C rec editor kindly weighs in!*) or [**interpretation**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25313426/are-void-elements-and-empty-elements-the-same).

Comment: @BoltClock: And ***Don't*** use [w3c-standards] for a question about [***applying* tech covered by the W3C standard**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class) (even if a would-be thorough answer may cite the standard).

Comment: I'd be down with that.

Answer (score 13):

First of all, let's see what problem we are going to solve. What's the problem? [That organization<sup>1</sup> tags are universally bad](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253910/792066). Be it Microsoft, Apple, Linux foundation, Twitter, Facebook, etc. these organizations normally create a plethora of products that developers consume (API, specifications, languages, etc.), which normally cause confusion and tend to make more difficult to people that are able to answer the questions to find them. So, that's [w3c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/w3c) problem.

The go to solution for these cases is to create new tags for each of the products that the organization offers. W3C being a "standards organization", its products are normally standards. So that leave us with [w3c-cgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/w3c-cgi), [w3c-html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/w3c-html), [w3c-mathml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/w3c-mathml), [w3c-svg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/w3c-svg), [w3c-xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/w3c-xml), [w3c-css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/w3c-css), etc.; except for that one problem: what those tags mean is already represented by non-prefixed tags, reducing the new tags to being redundant.

The sensible solution in this case is to replace the [w3c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/w3c) for the tag which captures the standard is being asked about.

But, what about the developer that wants to ask about implementing the standard as opposed to "use it"? Sadly, a cursory glance to the tag couldn't reveal any question about that... if you need help interpreting a standard, maybe using [language-lawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) which seems to be about those:

> For questions about the intricacies of formal or authoritative specifications of programming languages and environments.

---

<sup>1</sup> Normally, we call them companies, but organization is more general and captures the problem accurately.

Comment: In the web community we tend to call them "vendors". I will spend some time in the coming days retagging w3c questions to more appropriate tags. There are even seven questions tagged solely with [tag:w3c]!

Comment: I have never heard of [tag:language-lawyer] before. Maybe if it has some good synonyms it'll get used, but I wouldn't have known to look for that tag is I had asked a question about standards.

Comment: @TylerH when I said "we", it was with reference to the meta.SE crowd.

Comment: @Cerbrus that's because you don't use c++, those guys need to read the standard for anything!

Comment: @Braiam Yes, I assumed that much. I was just mentioning what the subject matter experts called them.

Comment: @Cerbrus And sometimes, not even reading the standard gives you the answer you're looking for, you need to get other people to scrutinise it for whatever it is that you missed!