# Sage Pay support directs to Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, outsourcing

The [Sage Pay support page](http://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/support-forum) appears to direct users to ask all support questions on Stack Overflow.

[image]

According to [several](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company) [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292309) [posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339549) on the topic, this is something we would prefer the company not do.  Can someone from the community team reach out to them?

Comment: That wording is particularly brazen too, usually they don't go so far as to encourage sharing comments with customers

Comment: That and their "see what others are saying has a wrong link, it should be http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sagepay

Comment: Why do companies do stuff like this - it makes them look so bad and unprofessional ughhhhhhhhhhhhhh

Comment: I _am_ mildly impressed that the "How does Stack Overflow work?" link is the Stack Overflow tour. I did not expect to see that. Their main description needs work, but the tour link and "About Stack Overflow" sections are better than I normally see in these posts.

Comment: our support forum has moved its now: https://www.google.com/search?q=sage+pay

Comment: It'd be fun if that *"See what others are saying"* links to this meta post.

Comment: I think the main problem is that they are using the word forum, which we are not

Comment: Also, their _"Ask a question"_ url links to `/users/login?returnurl=%2fquestions%2fask` instead of simply `/questions/ask`.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is appropriate but having worked in Sage head office for several years in the past I still have contacts there. I could find out who heads up Sage Pay support and pass their contact details to the community team if needed.

Comment: This is not *the* Sage Pay support page. Their main support page is http://www.sagepay.co.uk/support . So no, they don't direct users to ask *all* support questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: Is Sage Pay downsizing or cutting cost? Seems odd to use SO for support...

Comment: @AlvinBunk see other questions with the [outsourced] tag.  Sagepay is far from the first company to try and do this.  If the company doing so has its support people watching the tag and the instructions on their page correctly scope what can be asked to SO appropriate content (generally related to using an API) there's nothing wrong with doing so.  The problem is when sites doing so try to send people here for questions that are off topic by SO standards.

Comment: this actually seems reasonable, they include a how SO works post.

Comment: How did you navigate to the page in question? I clicked the link, and it worked, but I couldn't find it through their navigation.

Comment: Somehow we are OK with Canonical doing it... but not Sage? Sheesh... Canonical even got their own Stack out of it, complete with links to their own websites in the Stack's header... even though their products clearly fall into existing Stack categories.

Comment: I commented on the employee's answer, January 5th. No reply as of yet.

Comment: @user7138814 The support page you link to has plenty of FAQ type documents, and some newer guides that have gone live recently, but following the links to the "forum" comes straight back to SO, which is described as the replacement Sage Pay forum. In my experience, they are pretty good with telephone support, but that's also not the place for developers to share tech talk, ideas, techniques etc.